# What is #__VA_ARGS__ supposed to generate when there are no arguments passed?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

Example code:

```
#define FOO(...) You passed: #__VA_ARGS__
FOO(1,2,3)
FOO()
```

Preprocess with Visual C++ (version 14 CTP), get:

```
You passed: "1,2,3"
You passed:
```

In the last line, `#__VA_ARGS__` is turned into nothingness.  I would prefer it turned into "".

Is there a definitive reference for what is supposed to happen?  I Googled a lot but couldn't find it.

Any suggested work-around would also be useful.

Comment: It may be unspecified by the standard. I am currently getting `""` when I run under `gcc`'s preprocessor.

Comment: Did you have a look at the preprocessed source code or is there a chance that you are misinterpreting the output of your test program?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, does it? You can always concatenate the result into any string you like: `"Hello: " FOO() "!\n"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per **6.10.3.2 The # operator** (C11):

> #### Semantics
>
> 2 - [...] The character string literal corresponding to an empty argument is `""`.  [...]

So I think MSVC is incorrect here.

I would workaround this using string literal concatenation:

```
#define FOO(...) You passed: "" #__VA_ARGS__
```

Comment: Well, VC++ never pretended to implement C99 or C11 fully, so it's hard to say it is incorrect; it just is different.

Answer (score 4):

The paragraph in the standard (ISO14882:2011(e)) is a little bit lengthy, but its quite clear:

#### 16.3.2 The # operator

> <sup>2</sup> A *character string literal* is a *string-literal* with no
>   prefix. If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately
>   preceded by a # preprocessing token, both are replaced by a single
>   character string literal preprocessing token that contains the
>   spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding
>   argument. Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s
>   preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character
>   string literal. White space before the first preprocessing token and
>   after the last preprocessing token comprising the argument is deleted.
>   Otherwise, the original spelling of each preprocessing token in the
>   argument is retained in the character string literal, except for
>   special handling for producing the spelling of string literals and
>   character literals: a \ character is inserted before each " and \
>   character of a character literal or string literal (including the
>   delimiting " characters). If the replacement that results is not a
>   valid character string literal, the behavior is undefined. **The
>   character string literal corresponding to an empty argument is "".** The
>   order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.

And since

#### 16.3.1 Argument substitution

> <sup>2</sup> An identifier `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list
>   shall be treated as if it were a parameter, and the variable arguments
>   shall form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it.

this is the same for varags as it is for normal parameters.

Comment: Thanks; I tried it with a simple argument (`#define FOO(x)`) and it behaves the same.

Comment: @Bryan: Seems like a bug then to me. But ms people like to call such things "features", so unless you ask them (by filing a bugreport) we will never know.